# Can a Tiefling Monk access the Enlightened Fist PrC without dipping into a caster class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, tiefling, caster-level, feat-qualifications

Enlightened Fist has as a prerrequisite:

> Spells or Spell-Like Abilities: Arcane caster level 3rd.

A Tiefling has Darkness as a spell-like ability with a caster level equal to its character level. Unless I'm reading the prerrequisite wrong, a 3rd level or higher Tiefling could acces the PrC as long as he accomplishes the other prerrequisites (quite easily being a Monk), however, the spellcasting class feature reads like this:

> Spells per Day/Spells Known: Except at 1st level and 6th level, an
> enlightened fist gains new spells per day (and spells known, if
> applicable) as if she had also gained a level in an **arcane
> spellcasting class to which she belonged** before adding the prestige
> class level. She does not, however, gain any other benefit a character
> of that class would have gained (such as the bonus feat sometimes
> gained by a wizard). If she had more than one arcane spellcasting
> class before becoming an enlightened fist, she must decide to which
> class to add each level for the purpose of determining spells per day
> and spells known.

implying that he MUST have some levels in a caster class, and even if it didn't, a monk-only would have no list from where to draw spells, so... Can someone confirm if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enlightened fist requires spells or spell-like abilities with an **arcane** caster level; you don’t have one of those. Spell-like abilities are not usually arcane (or divine); exceptions are noted explicitly, e.g. with the warlock’s invocations.

Furthermore, even if your caster level was arcane (or we were talking about another prestige class that didn’t specify “arcane”), you do **not** have any classes you can choose with the “spells per day/spells known” class feature, and therefore that class feature is wasted and does nothing for you.

Comment: That... kinda sucks. Why include spell-like abilities if they are going to make a feature useless?

Comment: @Karrion42 It’s for warlocks (and dragonfire adepts, though the class hadn’t been printed yet when enlightened fist was); they use spell-like abilities and have a special rule where they can be chosen for prestige classes that progress spellcasting.

Comment: @Karrion42 Actually, correction—you can’t enter the class either. Forgot about the “arcane” requirement there.